# Menu dropdown ficando pra fora da tela em modo mobile em bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Eu to fazendo um projeto e meu menu dropdown quando está em modo mobile fica pra fora da tela desse modo aqui na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom2 ">
<button class="navbar-toggler pt-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><spam class="navbar-toggler-icon"></spam> Menu</button>

 <?php require_once('assets/includes/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php'); ?>
 <?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'      => 'Menu',
  'theme_location'  => 'menu-header',
  'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
  'container'       => 'div',
  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-custom',
  'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
  'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mx-auto mb-3 pt-2',
  'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
  'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()) 
  );
 ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Cara vc já deu uma olhada na documentação da Navbar do Bootstrap? Tem algumas coisa estranhas ai, primeiro que vc está colocando a navbar dentro de um container/row/col, depois que o button é fora da UL e não dentro.... Recomendo que veja esse link com o modelo oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Sim meu amigo, eu já vi. Button fora da ul ou dentro da ul não teve interferência alguma no meu problema, e o motivo de eu colocar a navbar dentro de um container/row é para deixar ele alinhado com o conteúdo do site.

Comment: Se testar o código sem as 4 primeiras divs, o erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: Se testar o código sem a ul, o erro continua o mesmo

Comment: Tente editar a pergunta é coca o código html já renderização na pagina, e não o php. Tipo inspeciona o menu direto no browser, pega o html da nav e cola aqui na pergunta, vai ajudar pra te responderem